# Recursive division over a list

Tags: python, recursion, division

I'm looking to divide every element of an list recursivly like this.

a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
so the returns would be 1/(2/(3/(4/5)))

```
def c(y):

    if not y:
        return 1  # division by 1 don't matter

    return c(y[1:])[0] / c(y[2:])[1]  # Not allowed
```

Comment: And where are you stuck? Have you tried debugging with plenty of print statements, or stepping through your program with a debugger? Have you tried outlining what the flow of your program should be with pen and paper (so you have the algorithm correct)?

Comment: Well yes.. This was only one of many weird looking functions and i'm suprise cause this was harder then i thought.

Comment: Nah, you're just making it harder than it is. The correct solution is much shorter/simpler.

Comment: I did try it with reduce but didn't get it to work there, or i might be doing ti wrong reduce(lambda x, y: x / y, [1,2,3,4]) does produce a float but not the right one..

Comment: What result do you expect, and what do you get?

Comment: @9769953 I'd like to see you do that alternative. Seems rather tricky.

Comment: @KellyBundy Which alternative?

Comment: @9769953 The one you proposed. With reduce and truediv.

Comment: Ah, I see: it's a continuous fraction, with the parentheses as they are.

Comment: `reduce(lambda x, y: y / x, [1,2,3,4,5])` seems to agree with `1/(2/(3/(4/5)))`. Now for the `truediv` implementation, which may indeed not be workable without a lambda. In which case `truediv` is not necessary.

Comment: @9769953 Nice, although for even lengths I think it's wrong. Better do the list in reverse.

Comment: ok im out of the rabbit hole now.
reduce(truediv, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) did the job. I did some typos in my tests and therefore thought i was wrong

Comment: @user15107839 No, that *is* wrong.

Comment: Recursion is **never** the right approach here. Just a regular loop would be much perferable. `reduce` is fine too, although, I would just use a for-loop since it is probably faster and easier to understand.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I disagree. The problem is recursive, so the recursive solution is natural.

Comment: @KellyBundy but there are practical considerations in Python with recursion, e.g., what if you want to work with `range(1,10000)`? That will be too big. Not to mention, highly time inefficient given the recursive implementations here, but it will always be limited by the stack, because there is no tail-call optimization

Comment: Recursion is not the best approach **in Python** if your arrays may have significant length due to stack limit, as @juanpa.arrivillaga pointed out

Comment: @KellyBundy although that `iter` approach is clever, and would at least not have quadratic time complexity, but it will be limited by the stack

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, not suitable for very long lists, but that might not be needed. About time inefficiency, do you mean the quadratic time? I just took care of that in my answer's update with my `d` version :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yours fixed and some mostly non-recursive alternatives (@9769953's fixed, and some by me):

```
for y in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]:
    print(y)

    def c(y):
        if not y:
            return 1
        return y[0] / c(y[1:])
    print(c(y))

    from functools import reduce
    print(reduce(lambda a, b: b / a, reversed(y)))

    from math import prod
    print(prod(y[::2]) / prod(y[1::2]))

    z = 1
    for x in reversed(y):
        z = x / z
    print(z)

    def d(y):
        y = iter(y)
        try:
            return next(y) / d(y)
        except StopIteration:
            return 1
    print(d(y))

    print()
```

Output showing the two test cases and the results of the five solutions ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZHBboMwDIbvfQofixRpo92mCWkPsPOOiAOQoEYqSeSaifDyzAYqsmqaT/n/OJ@TPyHSxbvze8B57jxCBOugzBWcFJwVvCh4rdSDoeCtKg7AFdA6OsbssChtOmhZrXtStgPnCeLuSKGhAR3khwcjls8VPAmizIsqSyYIlYcsToe@h25wLXl/vYHtg0dihB5akxxZjeO17htdQ62gKaBhOq/QfBu8GS3QLIH2NV3uvIBeJzSRfK2iOFUZQzaZL3pDTPCxPUlyHCXHZNCegPSNzJgS/JQk@Ls7crclgxLy3SP8O1BnRvkMZuu03YytCQRf5MMnk2qy3v3zIeuN9Jr4bmTz/AM)):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1.875
1.875
1.875
1.875
1.875

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
0.3125
0.3125
0.3125
0.3125
0.3125
```

Comment: Nice to have options. Personally, I think the `prod` implementation is the most readable, and should be efficient too

Comment: @frederick-douglas-pearce Hmm... Now that you mention it and you guys talked about long lists... I think the `prod` one is rather *inefficient*, as with long lists of ints, it builds two rather large ints with more and more expensive multiplications. And I just tried it with `y = range(1, 700)`, thinking it would *crash* due to those ints being too large to be converted to floats - which they *are*, but the division works anyway. I'm surprised.

Comment: Ahh, hadn't thought it through too much. Thanks for follow-up. Still think the `prod` implementation is the most readable, but see what you're saying about the expensive multiplications

Comment: @frederick-douglas-pearce Except for the base case, I actually find the recursive one (the `c` version) the most readable, as it directly implements the expression as given in the task description.

Answer (score 1):

Recursively, you can divide the first element by the result of recursing with the rest:

```
def recDiv(a):
    return a[0] / recDiv(a[1:]) if a else 1

a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print(recDiv(a_list)) # 1.875
```

Alternatively you could use the prod() function from math and apply a power of 1 or -1 depending on items being at even or odd positions.

```
a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

from math import prod

result = prod(n**[1,-1][i&1] for i,n in enumerate(a_list))

print(result) # 1.875
```

Which would translate into a regular loop like this:

```
result = 1
for i,n in enumerate(a_list):
    result *= n ** [1,-1][i&1]  # result *= 1/n if i%2 else n
    
print(result) # 1.875
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use simple recursion over the indices. For example:

```
a_list = [i + 1 for i in range(6)]


def divide(index: int = 0) -> float:
    if index == len(a_list):
        return 1
    return a_list[index] / divide(index + 1)


print(divide()) # 0.3125
```

Or, an equivalent implementation but with the list passed as an argument:

```
def divide(a_list: list, index: int = 0) -> float:
    if index == len(a_list):
        return 1
    return a_list[index] / divide(a_list, index + 1)

a_list = [i + 1 for i in range(6)]
print(divide(a_list)) # 0.3125
```

Or, using your original approach:

```
def divide(a_list: list) -> float:
    if not a_list:
        return 1
    n, *d = a_list
    return n / divide(d)


a_list = [i + 1 for i in range(6)]
print(divide(a_list)) # 0.3125
```